# Disabling Hyper-V on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, hyper-v

Yes, I know there are already many questions about how to disable hyper-v in windows 10 but none of them seem to work for me.

What I tried so far but without success:

- `Disable-Windows-OptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All`
- `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All`
- `bcdedit /set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype off`
- Disable/Enable Virtualization-Based-Security in Windows-Group-Policies
- Disabling Hyper-V and Windows-Hypervisor in Windows-Features
- Found a VB script on the internet but it also didn't work

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Dim backupfile
  Dim record
  Dim myshell
  Dim appmyshell
  Dim myresult
  Dim myline
  Dim makeactive
  Dim makepassive
  Dim reboot
  record=""
  Set myshell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  If WScript.Arguments.Length = 0 Then
      Set appmyshell  = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
      appmyshell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & WScript.ScriptFullName &     """ RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1
      WScript.Quit
  End if

  Set backupfile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  If Not (backupfile.FileExists("C:\bcdedit.bak")) Then
      Set myresult = myshell.Exec("cmd /c bcdedit /export c:\bcdedit.bak")
  End If

  Set myresult = myshell.Exec("cmd /c bcdedit")
  Do While Not myresult.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
      myline = myresult.StdOut.ReadLine()

      If myline="The boot configuration data store could not be opened." Then
          record=""
          exit do
      End If
      If Instr(myline, "identifier") > 0 Then
          record=""
          If Instr(myline, "{current}") > 0 Then
              record="current"
          End If
      End If
      If Instr(myline, "hypervisorlaunchtype") > 0 And record = "current" Then
          If Instr(myline, "Auto") > 0 Then
              record="1"
              Exit Do
          End If
          If Instr(myline, "On") > 0 Then
              record="1"
              Exit Do
          End If
          If Instr(myline, "Off") > 0 Then
              record="0"
              Exit Do
          End If
      End If
  Loop

  If record="1" Then
      makepassive = MsgBox ("Hypervisor status is active, do you want set to passive? ", vbYesNo, "Hypervisor")
      Select Case makepassive
      Case vbYes
          myshell.run "cmd.exe /C  bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off"
          reboot = MsgBox ("Hypervisor chenged to passive; Computer must reboot. Reboot now? ", vbYesNo, "Hypervisor")
          Select Case reboot
              Case vbYes
                  myshell.run "cmd.exe /C  shutdown /r /t 0"
          End Select
      Case vbNo
          MsgBox("Not Changed")
      End Select
  End If

  If record="0" Then
      makeactive = MsgBox ("Hypervisor status is passive, do you want set active? ", vbYesNo, "Hypervisor")
      Select Case makeactive
      Case vbYes
          myshell.run "cmd.exe /C  bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto"
          reboot = MsgBox ("Hypervisor changed to active;  Computer must reboot. Reboot now?", vbYesNo, "Hypervisor")
          Select Case reboot
              Case vbYes
                  myshell.run "cmd.exe /C  shutdown /r /t 0"
          End Select
      Case vbNo
          MsgBox("Not Changed")
      End Select
  End If

  If record="" Then
      MsgBox("Error: record can't find")
  End If
  ```

Does anyone have a solution besides what is listed above?

Comment: Have you disabled the services?

Comment: How are you verifying the solutions you have tried do not work?

Comment: @NiallJones yes

Comment: @Moab I still get an error message in vmware and virtualbox that hyper-v is still installed and i have to remove it in order to use other virtualization software

Comment: That doesn't mean it's Hyper-V.  What do the "Hyper-V Requirement" say when you run systeminfo?  "A hypervisor has been detected"?  If so, then it's Hyper-V, if you get four lines about VM monotir, virtualization enabled, SLAT, and DEP, then it's notm, its something else like your AV, device guard, etc.

Comment: @essjae it says: A hypervisor was detected. Features required by Hyper-V are not displayed.

Comment: I know you already stated you disabled services but that was the last thing that I tried (after all in your list) which allowed HyperV to finally be disabled for me.  Note there is a service named "HV Host Service" which is differently named than the others that start as "Hyper-V..."